# Convert a list to string in QGIS

Tags: qgis, list, string

I have edited a field into the attribute form of a QGIS project as a "Value Relation" to create a checkbox where I can choose few possibilities. I have a tree sickness and the field I am talking about is the LOCATION where the sickness is visible: Roots, leaves, trunk, branches, twigs. The thing is that the output of all of that when I open my attribute table after typing the data it is like this in case the sickness is in all parts of the tree:

```
{"Roots","Trunk","Braches","Leaves","Twigs"}
```

Is there anyway where I can transform this into a normal string when it comes to be readable on the attribute table like `Roots, Trunk, Branches, Leaves and Twigs` (without the `and` also good solution but for sure without curly braces and quotation marks)?

Comment: Try this `regexp_replace('{"Roots","Trunk","Braches","Leaves","Twigs"}','\\{|}|"','')`

Answer (score 3):

If you try to change/remove curly brackets in-place, you ruin "Value Relation" concept. Therefore, you should add a new field and use an expression like this:

```
replace(regexp_replace("LOCATION", '\\{|}|"', ''), ',', ', ')
```

It removes `{`, `}`, `"` and changes`,`(comma) to `,`  (comma+space). It changes, for example, `{"Roots","Branches","Twigs"}` to `Roots, Branches, Twigs`.